# Android gps what it means?

Tags: android, gps

I got this little line(s):

```
int meter = 1;
update 5000; //1 ms
globalconstant.mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, (long) update, meter,globalconstant.mlocListener);
```

can someone tell me what is that mean ? Is that mean the gps update time is 5 second and if there's a location change 1 meter it refresh in 5 sec maybe 4 times if i 4 times move 1 meter in 5 sec ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iirc it means that it will check for location once every 5 seconds, and after each check, if you have moved more than 1 meter, it will notify the mlocListener.  (if you haven't moved more than 1 meter, it will not notify)

This means you will get *at most* 1 update every 5 seconds - but it might be less (ie if you're not moving, your app won't get location updates).

At least, that's how it should work.  Given GPS inaccuracy, etc, you may end up getting location updates even when you're standing still (I think - been a while since I played with the GPS code)

Comment: No, you are wrong, it is not going to check for every 5 seconds, otherwise battery will drain soon and also system will get hang, as per the doc, it is min time req to fetch the GPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Location Manager [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). The syntax is  [requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29)

- provider, which either GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER
- minTime is the Minimum time required for fetching the GPS signal
- minDistance , Minimum change in lat-lon co-ordinates
- listener , LocationLister which listens for the GPS signal

So in your case it will take atleast 5 seconds to fetch GPS and distance precision can be 1 meter.

Answer (score -1):

It means that GPS will try to calculate device position every 5 seconds. If the new position calculated is more then 1 meter away from the previous one, then it will call the LocationListener with the new Location as argument. If the new position is closer then one meter to the previous one, it will be discarded and the Listener will not be called.

Check documentation in here: [Location Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29)

Comment: how much should be the meter? what is the usual?

Comment: It's up to your needs. You must decide what you need in termes of receing new positions updates.